# Swift init with function to make clear separation

Tags: swift

In ObjC I used to call in my init something like

```
- init() {
[self initView1]
[self initView2]
}
```

to separate the setup of the views

but in swift I can't call a function before any variable has been set, is there something I'm missing or it's not possible ?

Comment: This should be possible after you have called `super.init()`. Or am I missing something?

Comment: I don't have a super, and my variables are set in their respective initViewX

Comment: That's not possible, as far as I know.

Comment: I'm trying to separate stuff in extension, so I have a fake init in the extension that I want to call in the real init

Comment: self is any custom class

Comment: One possibility is to make the properties lazy.

Comment: All of `self`'s properties have to be set before any of `self`'s methods can be called - but you can do this by either making them lazy (as @dasdom pointed out), or by setting them to default values before your methods are called to - either in their declaration or in `init` - or by using optionals and setting them to nil.

Comment: One more way is to make the properties optional (either implicitly unwrapped or not - it's up to you and your plans).

Comment: looks like something called mixins
http://matthijshollemans.com/2015/07/22/mixins-and-traits-in-swift-2/

Answer (score 1):

You can assign an initial value on their declaration line:

```
class MyClass {
    var prop1: String = ""
    var prop2: String = ""

    init() {
        self.initView1()
        self.initView2()
    }

    func initView1() {
        self.prop1 = "Hello"
    }

    func initView2() {
        self.prop2 = "World"
    }
}
```

Or alternatively, make them implicitly unwrapped optionals by adding an exclamation mark (`!`):

```
    var prop1: String!
    var prop2: String!
```

This tell the compiler that the programmer has guaranteed that these properties will be properly initialized before use.

Comment: I tried using protocol default implementation, and having a default value breaks the default implementation using a computed var in the protocol extension

Comment: Then use implicitly unwrapped optionals.

Answer (score 0):

In Swift, every property must be initialized before you can call methods.

This is described in detail in the chapter [Two-Phase Initialization](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-ID220) of the Swift Programming Language Manual.

If you want to delegate initialization to a method, then you at least have to provide some dummy values first.

Alternatively, you can refactor your code to create your views from static methods (if that is possible); then you can use these objects for initialization:

```
class MyClass {
  let prop1: String
  let prop2: String

  static func create1() -> String {
    return "Hello"
  }

  static func create2() -> String {
    return "World"
  }

  init() {
    prop1 = Blah.create1()
    prop2 = Blah.create2()
  }
}
```